# Can not export webpack.config when modules:false

Tags: reactjs, module, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

Inside my index.js I am using webpack-dev-middleware/webpack-hot-middleware where I require my webpack.config and use it for compiler.

**index.js**

```
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config.js')
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    noInfo: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  }))

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler))
```

I try to export my webpack.config using *Common.js* by *require* and *module.exports* but I get error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

**webpack.config**

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client')
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src')


process.noDeprecation = true

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  context: publicPath,
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=false&noInfo=true',
      'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'script-loader!tether/dist/js/tether.min.js',
      'script-loader!bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      './app.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(buildPath, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      CountdownForm: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/scenes/countdown/components/CountdownForm.jsx'),
      Countdown: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/scenes/countdown/index.jsx'),
     ..
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|dist|build/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: [
            [
              'babel-plugin-react-css-modules',
              {
                context: publicPath,
                filetypes: {
                  '.scss': 'postcss-scss'
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.local\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
              resources: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client/styles/global/sass-resources.scss')
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.local).)+\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

If I use ES6 (I am using babel and this usually works) using *import* statements at the top instead of require and *export default* instead of module.exports I get this error

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration misses the property 'entry'.
```

All of this is because of **modules:false** inside my **.babelrc** If I remove that Common.js way works, but I need this. How can I export webpack.config to compiler using modules:false

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform-runtime` adds `import` and that results in mixing `import` with your `module.exports`.

Simple fix would be to replace `module.exports` with es6 `export`

```
module.exports = { ...webpackconfig }
```

becomes

```
export default { ...webpackconfig }
```

and update your index.js to use default export

```
const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config.js').default
```

---

You can find more information about this on these issues

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3917

Comment: Thanks rzr. It works. Can we just elaborate this a bit, to see if I get it. So, I can use common.js where I use module.exports but I cannot mix it with imports in the same file? If I use imports I must use export default and require it with .default at the end? I can use require with either module.exports or export default but with module.exports I don’t need to use .default at the end? And lastly they cannot mix inside one file but can across the project?